# Is there an alternative to Google's JOBB tool?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

My Android app is larger than the 50 MB limit Google Play imposes so I have to generate a `.obb` file for it. However, I have come to find that the JOBB tool Google provides is incredibly buggy. I'm trying to create an encrypted `.obb` file, but depending on the content of the folder I'm packing into the `.obb`, sometimes the output file is corrupted and can't be be mounted, or it can be mounted but some files inside the `obb` are corrupted.

Is there an alternative to Google's JOBB tool? This one seems to have been developed by a 5 year old.

Comment: What is the size of your apk as of now without .obb files?

Comment: @MehulJoisar Still larger than the 100MB new limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there aren't any options that would allow you to mount the file like Google's buggy JOBB tool. If mounting is not a requirement, thankfully there's still salvation. The best option I could find that allows encryption is:

- Use a tool that supports compression in the zip format and encryption using AES 128, AES 256, or standard zip encryption. Be aware that some encryption algorithms are not very secure; AES 256 is one of the strongest you can use. One of the best tools to do the job is [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).
- Use [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/), a Java library that among many other features, allows you to read straight from the zip file and supports the encryption methods mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are no alternative to JOBB tool. But you can try to get the latest sources of this tool from [Android Git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/tools-canary-release/jobb/) and build. May be they fixed some bugs but haven't released yet.

Comment: Here I am in 2017 and the jobb tool distributed with the android SDK is still buggy :(